# How to add a list as variable to sqllite table?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an application that needs to hold a list of projects, 
- every project has several properties, 
some of them are normal integers strings and Boolean, 
and some of them are lists, simple ones and more complicated ones.

I'm holding all this data in an sql table. As I assume, it's the simplest way to save that data offline.

I wanted to know, I know how to do the simple TEXT, INTEGER, 
but how do I add a List as a variable ?

To clarify. 
This is what I do now:

```
mydatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Projects(name TEXT, description TEXT, networkId TEXT);");
```

This is what I want to do:

```
mydatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Projects(name TEXT, description TEXT, list1 ArrayList<String>, list2 ArrayList<String> , costumeList1 ArrayList<CostumModel>, costumeList1 ArrayList<CostumModel2>, networkId TEXT);");
```

How can this be done ? 
I was looking online for this and couldn't find too much help.
thnx !

Comment: Maybe you've mistaken with `mysql` tag? Are you asking about android and `sqlite`?

Comment: yea +g2s8 i changed it thnx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such builtin sqlite type as `list` or `array`. To save collection to sqlite you should chose one of two approaches: **create another table** with relation to origin table or **serialize your list to string** (e.g. json string) and save as text.

#### Another table

Create new table for *costumeList1* (from your sample):

```
CREATE TABLE costumes (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    project_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(project_id) REFERENCES Projects(_id)
);
```

and select costumes by project:

```
SELECT name FROM costumes WHERE project_id = ?
```

This approach is good if your *costumes* can be extended with additional field, like model or count. It will be easy to update existing table for new entity:

```
ALTER TABLE costumes ADD COLUMN model TEXT;
```

#### Serialize

If your costumes just an array, you can serialize it to string (e.g. json string):

```
new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(costumeList1)).toString();
```

and save this string as `TEXT` field in database.
To get this array back you should deserialize it:

```
new JsonArray(cursor.getString("costumeList1"))
```